# Make Mongoose property no longer unique

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Im getting a bizarre error with Mongoose. When a user registers they give the name of the organisation they belong to. Previously, this needed to be unique. My schema was:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var Organisation = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  createdById: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  },
  createdOn: {
    type: Date,
    "default": Date.now
  },
  availableUntil: {
    type: Date
  }
});

Organisation.path('name').validate(function(value, done) {
  var self = this;

  if (!self.isNew) {
    return done(true);
  } else {
    //mongoose.models['Organisation'] or self.model('Organisation')
    mongoose.models['Organisation'].count({
      name: value
    }, function(err, count) {
      if (err) {
        return done(err);
      }

      return done(!count)
    });
  }
}, "This email already exists");

mongoose.model('Organisation', Organisation);
```

But now it doesn't matter, an organisation name doesn't need to be unique. So I changed to:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var Organisation = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  createdById: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  },
  createdOn: {
    type: Date,
    "default": Date.now
  },
  availableUntil: {
    type: Date
  }
});


mongoose.model('Organisation', Organisation);
```

Note how `unique: true` has been removed.

I've restarted the server but bizarrely, I still get the error:

```
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'E11000 duplicate key error index: redmatter.organisations.$name_1 dup key: { : "delete me" }',
  driver: true,
  code: 11000,
  index: 0,
  errmsg: 'E11000 duplicate key error index: redmatter.organisations.$name_1 dup key: { : "delete me" }',
  getOperation: [Function],
  toJSON: [Function],
  toString: [Function] }
```

How is this possible? Why am I getting a duplicate key error when I don't care if the name is not unique?

Comment: "Note how unique: true has been removed." -> nope?

Comment: oops typo, it has been removed, same error

Comment: Figured it out, i had to remove index https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-indexes/#remove-indexes

Comment: Yes, removing from the code doesn't change anything once the code has fired at least once. That's because mongoose will create the unique index. You have to drop it on the database's side.